# For loop not working -> google sheets to google form automated data entry

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms, google-apps-script-editor

Using videos, I located the script that automates data entry from Google Sheets to Google Forms. I added this in the script editor in Google Sheets and it works perfectly for one row's data, but it is not working for multiple rows. Another video introduced the for loop, and I am following the syntax as shown, but I am still only pulling one row's data.

```
for (var i=2; i<=7;i++){

var ename = wrkSht.getRange('A'+ i).getValue();
var dept = wrkSht.getRange('B'+ i).getValue();
var shift = wrkSht.getRange('C'+ i).getValue();
var position = wrkSht.getRange('D'+ i).getValue();
var supervisor = wrkSht.getRange('E'+ i).getValue();
var WorkIns = wrkSht.getRange('F'+ i).getValue();

var datamap={
"entry.1827722981":ename,
"entry.810555316": dept,
"entry.499513951": shift,
"entry.2061009493": position,
"entry.1377736413": supervisor,
"entry.203834251": WorkIns}

 var options = {
   "method" : "post",
   "payload": datamap
 };

};
```

Any and all information is helpful. NOTE: My role is not a technical one so my knowledge is elementary at best.

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? You're overriding the data inside datamap and then not using it. You probably should make each request (I'm guessing this is what you're doing) at the end of the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks @AndresDuarte. I found a solution but now I have another question. I want to get the data for columns A through F for each row that has data. My loop works now, but I want the script to break when there is no more data and the cells are empty.

Comment: If you have a valid answer please [post it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so it can be documented for future references. For the other question, please open a new question with the [google-apps-script] tag and we'll take a look.